# child divs extending out of parent div

Tags: css, layout, html

I want to place two images together in the top banner.
But the second image is showing outside the "banner" parent div.
I've tried with tables too, but not getting the results.
Also two images should not fold when I resize the browser. What's the right way to do this? One way is to join the images in Photoshop which I don't want to do.

```
<div id="banner">
    <div><img src=".." alt="Utilities Logo" 
    height="105" width="406" /></div>
    <div>
    <img src=".." alt="!" 
    height="105" width="467">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "I want to place two images together" means side by side? if yes try to assign float property to the divs containing the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the easiest way. Images are inline-block, so they will align nice (#banner should not be smaller than 406+467 though).

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src=".." alt="Utilities Logo" height="105" width="406" /><img src=".." alt="!"  height="105" width="467">
</div>
```

An another way might be to play with the `float` CSS property, as michele suggested.

If you really don't want them to fold on browser resize, you should consider merging them in PS because then I don't really see a good reason for them to be separate. Or you can give #banner a CSS `min-width` big enough to hold the two images.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some id's to the div's

```
   <div id="banner">
        <div id="img1">
            <img src=".." alt="Utilities Logo" height="105" width="406" />
        </div id="img2">
        <div>
            <img src=".." alt="!" height="105" width="467">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then try the following css

```
#img1 
{
    float : left;
    width : 406px;
}

#img2 
{
    float : left;
    width : 467px;
}
```

That should solve the issue

Comment: I think on making window small the second image will be "folded"

Comment: what exactly do you mean by folded ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="image_1">
    </div>
    <div id="image_2">
    </div>
</div>

#image_1 { height:105px; width:406px; float:left; background:url(file_path_to_image/name_of_image.png) no-repeat; }

#image_2 { height:105px; width:467px; float:left; background:url(file_path_to_image/name_of_image.png) no-repeat; }
```

Also I would make sure that `#banner <div>` has at least a width of 467px.

You have not been specific if you want those two `<divs>` on top of eachother. If you don't want them to be horizontally aligned left to right as they will be with my above code. Simply take out the `float:left;` Just make sure there is a minimum width of 467px on the `#banner div and` that should do it.

Comment: If we make window small the second float will fold down. In a banner this is not expected.

Comment: Like I said, you are not being specific enough about your exact positioning that you want. Also, not specific enough in example ( link,image example etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #banner { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<div id="banner">
    <img src="banner-1.png" width="406" height="105">
    <img src="banner-2.png" width="467" height="105">
</div>
```